# Material UI - Tabs : How to group or collapse Tab

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using Material-UI and have used their **Tabs API** to make a vertical tabs. On TabPanel I am displaying the content and every thing works fine so far.

Now, the number of Tab items are growing, So I must group them on their categories. But I could not find any property which handle the child tab or collapsible property to support grouping the tabs. Atleast this information is not available on [Material-UI website](https://material-ui.com/components/tabs/) .

To group them I tried their expansionPanel api, but that does not work and tab alignments becomes horizontal and disturbs the tabs section. Also tried collapse api but then the tabs are not working and alignment gets disturbed.. So struggling.
Kindly help me.

- --Tab1
- --Tab2
- --**Tab3 ^**

  - ---Tab4
  - ---Tab5
  - ---Tab6

Comment: In this page videos show how it should work https://material.io/design/navigation/navigation-transitions.html#about-navigation-transitions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to use the `<List>` and the `<Collapse>` components, and not the `<Tab>` component for this.

Here is a usage example:

```
import List from '@material-ui/core/List';
import ListItem from '@material-ui/core/ListItem';
import Collapse from '@material-ui/core/Collapse';
import ExpandLess from '@material-ui/icons/ExpandLess';
import ExpandMore from '@material-ui/icons/ExpandMore';


export default function NestedList() {
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(true);

  const handleClick = () => {
    setOpen(!open);
  };

  return (
    <List component="nav">
      <ListItem button>
        Tab 1
      </ListItem>
      <ListItem button>
        Tab 2
      </ListItem>
      <ListItem button onClick={handleClick}>
        Tab 3
        {open ? <ExpandLess /> : <ExpandMore />}
      </ListItem>
      <Collapse in={open} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
        <List component="div" disablePadding>
          <ListItem button>
            Tab 4
          </ListItem>
          <ListItem button>
            Tab 5
          </ListItem>
          <ListItem button>
            Tab 6
          </ListItem>
        </List>
      </Collapse>
    </List>
  );
}
```

Comment: How it will display the selected listItem content. I mean the way when user clicks on a listItem, I have to show the page on right hand side like TabPanel Works..

Comment: Thanks @Dekel. It works with little change. Your code displays listItems in horizontal. So,  I used <List><ListItem button><ListItemText primary="Tab1">  from Material-Ui demo section. Also I put a onClick function to populate a value and used that to display in right section description. So not it works like Tabs and TabPanel . marked as answer